# May I delete cache and application support for Xcode? I'm using App cleaner

Tags: xcode, disk-space

[image]

I downloaded Appcleaner from App store and want to clean up to get some more space.

I have two versions of Xcode; 7.3 and 8.0. So there's no problem with two executable files but I'm wondering what that 'Application support' files are for. The bigger one takes up almost 19 gigabytes..

May i delete that one?

Comment: While this is not a direct answer, [this article](http://ajithrnayak.com/post/95441624221/xcode-users-can-free-up-space-on-your-mac) is a few years old but provides info on Xcode folders and what they're used for. You can see if it's safe to delete.  Credit to [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33322832/3487310).

Comment: You can safely delete *some* of these. See https://superuser.com/a/1147209/430478.

Answer (score 5):

- Cache: Sure. Haven't noticed anything bad. (You can do this yourself, as well – just trash everything in `~/Library/Caches`.)
- Application Support: **Do not do this without knowing what's in there!** Apps often use this to store configuration – for example:

  - Xcode puts color themes and key bindings there.
  - The Dock puts your spaces configuration there.
  - GIMP uses it to hold all sorts of things like gradients and palette images.
  - Steam uses it to store your *entire game library*. (If it's taking up way too much space, try uninstalling some games.) Not sure if progress is there too, but it seems likely.

Deleting Application Support **won't break the app** (it'll just create it again the next time it starts), but you might **lose configuration** and other data, like key bindings for Xcode. You also might want to make sure the app is closed before you take its folders out from under it. (:

Answer (score -2):

I am using AppCleaner and I searched for this question specifically because I downloaded Xcode 9 with 8.3 still installed on my mac.
Long story short; you can safely delete Application Support if you do not have any issue with losing any or all configurations previously set on the app. I did it for a bunch of apps like Spotify to free up space and as far as I can tell everything works smoothly.

Comment: Um...many apps stick configuration files in there. Whether you can delete it safely depends on the app—look before you trash!

Comment: Yes I agree. I deleted mine after much internal deliberation. Due to a few reasons I did not install Xcode from the app store and ended up with dual installs. As a result I had multiple configurations in that folder which were actually obvious because I had renamed my first Xcode to 8.33. I guess my answer actually applies to me an anyone in a similar scenario to mine. FYI the folder was 17.7gb. I think this was a fair decision imo. If I notice any glitches while using Xcode I will be sure to update but my guess is that the app is reset to default configuration. I am editing my answer thanks!

Comment: Ouch, that's _huge_! Yeah, it shouldn't break anything. (BTW, mine's only 49 KB -- I wonder what was in yours.)